# Combining MS Word "track changes" comments from multiple readers/editors

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, comments

I am a writer and use MS Word (Mac 2011) for pretty much everything, and especially the [Track Changes](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Track-changes-while-you-edit-024158a3-7e62-4f05-8bb7-dc3ecf0295c4) function, which allows you to add comments to the document. I have been circulating my work to some readers. Some have added comments to their copies of the Word document with "track changes," and some have printed out the Word document and given me hand-written comments.

I'd like to combine all of these comments into one document using the Track Changes feature. Is it possible (a) to combine the comments from multiple documents, while maintaining that different users (with different names) added the comments and changes, and (b) to manually add the hand-written comments as different "users" in Track Changes? That way I can see all of the comments side-by-side.

Comment: You wouldn't just make the recommended changes based on the hardcopy document in front of you along with looking at the recommended changes in the Word document?

Comment: It's not just recommended changes - it's comments / questions. I'd like to be able to see them all side-by-side instead of having to have 3-5 copies of the same printed pages in front of me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to do is to:

- Sign out of your Windows Live, Office 365 account
- Create a separate Windows Live account
- Login using the enw account...
- Add new comments or transcribe the changes on paper to online.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using Office for Mac?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Office for Mac. Maybe there is a way to change the user properties before you start editing. I can appreciate you wanting to be able to see everything in once place. A few options... 1) force everyone to use Word to make changes, 2) use Google Docs instead.